# How would i access the properties in this object? Twitter API

Tags: php, arrays, object, twitter

I have stores this object in an variable called results. How would i access the profile_image_url for example.

Here is the return value with print_r:

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [results] => Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
      [profile_image_url] => http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/685278639/twitter-logo_normal.jpg 
      [created_at] => Mon, 10 May 2010 11:29:44 +0000 
      [from_user] => BarclaysWealth 
      [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [result_type] => recent ) 
      [to_user_id] => 
      [text] => RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7 
      [id] => 13721505359 
      [from_user_id] => 14895786 
      [geo] => 
      [iso_language_code] => en 
      [source] => <a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>  ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
      [profile_image_url] => http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/671523082/32fb0a8_normal.jpg 
      [created_at] => Fri, 07 May 2010 21:02:10 +0000 
      [from_user] => InfoFocus 
      [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [result_type] => recent ) 
      [to_user_id] => 
      [text] => RT @BarclaysWealth: RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7 
      [id] => 13569384857 
      [from_user_id] => 85742792 
      [geo] => [iso_language_code] => en 
      [source] => <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>  ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
      [profile_image_url] => http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/685278639/twitter-logo_normal.jpg 
      [created_at] => Fri, 07 May 2010 20:59:20 +0000 
      [from_user] => BarclaysWealth 
      [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [result_type] => recent ) 
      [to_user_id] => 
      [text] => RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7 
      [id] => 13569257933  
      [from_user_id] => 14895786  
      [geo] =>  
      [iso_language_code] => en  
      [source] => <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>  )  
    [3] => stdClass Object (  
      [profile_image_url] => http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/485934856/BD_Icon_Twitter_small_normal.gif  
      [created_at] => Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:56 +0000  
      [from_user] => BARXdirect  
      [metadata] => stdClass Object (  
        [result_type] => recent )  
      [to_user_id] =>  
      [text] => RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7 
      [id] => 13557670463  
      [from_user_id] => 66715243  
      [geo] =>  
      [iso_language_code] => en  
      [source] => <a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>  )  
    [4] => stdClass Object (  
      [profile_image_url] => http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/431590520/BSL_icon_normal.gif 
      [created_at] => Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:12 +0000  
      [from_user] => BarclaysStock  
      [metadata] => stdClass Object (  
        [result_type] => recent )  
      [to_user_id] =>  
      [text] => Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7  
      [id] => 13557633799  
      [from_user_id] => 36238006  
      [geo] =>  
      [iso_language_code] => en  
      [source] => <a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>  ) )  
  [max_id] => 13722716932 
  [since_id] => 0  
  [refresh_url] => ?since_id=13722716932&q=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FOaYh7  
  [results_per_page] => 15  
  [page] => 1  
  [completed_in] => 0.026887  
  [query] => http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FOaYh7 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some basic access examples:

```
//get a single profile url
echo $results->results[0]->profile_image_url;
//or
$tweet = $results->results[0];
echo $tweet->profile_image_url;

//get all the profile urls
foreach($results->results as $tweets){
  echo $tweet->profile_image_url;
}
```

Of course the same basic concept applies to all the other properties, except (for this specific example data) the `metadata` property, which is an object.

```
//to get result type
echo $results->results[0]->metadata->result_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: $imageURL = $obj->results[0]->profile_image_url;

Answer (score 0):

```
$object['results'][0]->profile_image_url
```

If the first object is an array, than this is the way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work.

```
$test = $response->results[0]->id;
print_r($test);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer does not appear to address the original question, which is 7 years old and already has an accepted answer. Your efforts would be better used answering new questions.