# How to Handle/Use Twitter API's stdClass Object?

Tags: php, twitter

Wait you don't need to read the whole thing :) Just scroll down, and see what I've asked.

```
stdClass Object
    (
    [friends_count] => 54
    [description] => i'TS THE digiTAL vERSiOn 0b devilZ! tECH & mUUsic fReak.

    sImpLE buT.......! 
    [screen_name] => 2020Volt
    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => 181A1E
    [status] => stdClass Object
    (
    [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 83300174
    [place] => 
    [coordinates] => 
    [contributors] => 
    [in_reply_to_screen_name] => Anik1990
    [geo] => 
    [retweet_count] => 
    [source] => Seesmic Web
    [retweeted] => 
    [in_reply_to_status_id] => 29180026185
    [created_at] => Sat Oct 30 13:04:53 +0000 2010
    [in_reply_to_user_id] => 83300174
    [truncated] => 
    [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 29180026185
    [id] => 29181306201
    [id_str] => 29181306201
    [favorited] => 
    [text] => @Anik1990 its just my point of view man.....
    )

    [geo_enabled] => 1
    [follow_request_sent] => 
    [time_zone] => Dhaka
    [favourites_count] => 1
    [verified] => 
    [notifications] => 
    [profile_background_color] => 1A1B1F
    [url] => http://techysafi.wordpress.com
    [lang] => en
    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
    [created_at] => Tue Sep 21 15:28:38 +0000 2010
    [profile_text_color] => 666666
    [location] => Dhaka,Bangladesh[listed_count] => 6
    [protected] => 
    [statuses_count] => 1962
    [profile_background_image_url] => http://s.twimg.com/a/1288217225/images/themes/theme9/bg.gif
    [profile_link_color] => 2FC2EF
    [name] => Tech Freak Satan
    [show_all_inline_media] => 
    [following] => 
    [profile_image_url] => http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1146520409/SDC11078_normal.jpg
    [id] => 193332358
    [id_str] => 193332358
    [contributors_enabled] => 
    [profile_background_tile] => 
    [utc_offset] => 21600
    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => 252429
    [followers_count] => 60
    )
```

Now my Question is HOW I can turn [text] into a variable like $tweet ?? and the [name] as well. Because I want to store them on mysql, so I need to retrieve the value of [text] & [name] !

$sdjkf->status->text; this is not returning anything !

I saw a related post [How would i access the properties in this object? Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803079/how-would-i-access-the-properties-in-this-object-twitter-api) on here but my case is kinda different. Just browse this link, if you wish.

(Im begging your pardon, pls don't treat me as a professional so whatever you gonna say, say it completely & clearly...and I know Im stupid :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have the `stdClass` object (as you listed above) stored in a php variable called `$response`, you can put the `text` attribute into a php variable called `$tweet` like this:

```
$tweet = $response->status->text;
```

likewise, with the name:

```
$tweeter_name = $response->screen_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach()` loop to get the object values in loop something like the following :

```
foreach($tweet as $value)
{echo "Screen Name : ".$value->screen_name."<br>";
echo "Tweet : ". $value->text."<br>";
}
```